# How to use Shark-CLI library with 2 USB connected devices?

Tags: memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am unable to use the Shark-CLI library with 2 devices connected to the computer. Is there any parameter to select which device will be used by the library?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by Shark-CLI, I filed an issue here: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/1642 . It's open source, if you're interested you can add support for it.

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Yves Ricau, I saw at github issue [https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/1642] that this support was implemented. When it will be available on Shark-CLI beta release? Thanks for your support.

Comment: It's available in LeakCanary 2 which was released last week. If this answered your question, don't hesitate to validate the answer ;)

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Yves Ricau, it's working perfectly. Thanks for quick reply the anwser.